# Solving $\frac{1}{5^p} + (\frac{7}{10})^p = 1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How can i analiticaly solve equations like:

$$
(1/5^p) + (7/10)^p = 1
$$

Or

$$
(1/5^p) + (3/8)^p = 1
$$

The goal is to find $p$.

I thought maybe to do $log$ but it seems that it doesnt get me anywhere.

Can you give me a direction?

Thanks.

Comment: what makes you think that this can be solved explicitly?

Answer (score 3):

After one step we get,
$7^p+ 2^p=10^p$
Here 
Odd+even=even
Which is impossible
Contradiction!!!
No solution..I think it is helpful
If any thing wrong then ask

Comment: P can be irrational also

Comment: nice observation

Comment: @Arjang What is nice here?

Comment: that for integer values, there is no solution. Even that was not the question, it is still a good side catch. The original question might have no answer, but this is an answer to a better question.

Answer (score 2):

Clearly map: 
$
f(p)= (1/5^p) + (7/10)^p 
$
is decreasing so given equation has at most one solution. Since $f(0)= 2$ and $f(1) = 9/10$ and $f$ is continuous the solution is in $(0,1)$. Now try with some aproximation method, like tangent method...

Also, this means that there is no solution in $\mathbb{Z}$.